# Casperjs- How can I type strings in a field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write enter a question title with the following casperjs but Casper fails to recognize the text input feild.

Here is my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.fillXPath('form', {
    'html body div#app-root.spg-survey-wrapper div.sp-survey main.sp-survey-content section.sp-question-container div#question-editor section.sp-question-editor-wrapper.sp-question-editor-wrapper-no-footer main.sp-question-canvas textarea.sp-question-title': 'Question One'
  }, true);
});
```

Here is the the inspect element:

```
<textarea data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.0.2.$51192b31-b50f-4593-9039-2434d512d646=2label" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 44, 64); height: 65px;" value="" placeholder="Enter question here." class="sp-question-title"></textarea>
```

Thanks